# Django + Factory Boy: How to use a named parameter to control behavior of factory.Maybe + factory.RelatedFactory

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

Is there a way to define a named parameter (that is not a model attribute) to control the behavior of **factory.Maybe**?

For example: I want to create a named parameter that controls the creation of a **RelatedFactory** through a **Maybe** condition, I tried to do this:

```
# factories.py
class Purchase(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    user = factory.SubFactory('project.factories.UserFactory')
    total = uniform(10, 100)

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase

class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    first_name = factory.Faker('first_name')
    last_name = factory.Faker('last_name')

    has_purchase = False
    purchases = factory.Maybe(
        'has_purchase',
        yes_declaration=factory.RelatedFactory(Purchase, 'purchase'),
        no_declaration=None
    )

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['has_purchase', 'purchases']
        model = User

# tests.py
user_without_purchase = UserFactory.create()
user_with_purchase = UserFactory.create(has_purchase=True)
```

It seems that I can't change the value of **has_purchase** through the named parameter, it's always set as False. I don't know if it's because both fields are declared in **exclude** Meta attribute. And I have to put them in **exclude** or else *DjangoModelFactory* tries to use these fields when saving it to the database, which causes an Integrity error.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that factory boy have a feature to provided additional parameters without having to add theses fields to the `exclude` attribute: http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#simple-parameters:

```
class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Params:
        has_purchase = False
```

Used in conjunction with the http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#lazyattribute maybe ?

Comment: thanks but I guess this doesn't work, if I remove the "exclude" and move both fields to class Params, "Maybe" is not able to read has_purchase parameter (I don't know why)

Comment: I don't think you should move the `purchases` attributes. Because inside the `Params`, as you said, it will not read the `has_purchase` (so you will still need the exclude after all). Did you try with the `lazyAttribute` ?

Comment: Yes, but even with LazyAttribute Django manager throws the following error: "'purchases' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: Even with still this attribute in the `exclude` list ?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Clément Denoix's answer, I've been able to add an optional argument to pass a value directly to a sub-factory (a shortcut, sort of):

```
class Y_Factory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Y  # has a field named 'z'


class X_Factory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = X  # has a foreign key to Y

    class Params:
        z = None

    y = factory.lazy_attribute(lambda o: Y_Factory(z=o.z or 'default_z'))
```

Now the following syntax `X_Factory(y=Y_Factory(z=z))` can be simplified to `X_Factory(z=z)`.

There is one caveat though: using this syntax will mislead newcomers as it wrongly depicts the data structure. Still, I decided that in one particular case, such a shortcut conveniently removed some annoying boilerplate code from my fixtures and was worth the trade-off.